# How can I get Superclass object

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

How can I get Superclass object if I call super constructor from Subclass?

```java
class Superclass implements Serializable {
    int count;
    String name;
    public Superclass(int count, String name) {
        this.count = count;
        this.name = name;
   }
}

class Subclass extends Superclass implements Serializable {
    public Subclass() {
        super(1, "first");
   }
}
```

something like:

```java
Subclass subclass = new Subclass();
Superclass superclass = subclass.getClass().getSuperclass();
superclass.getName();
```

Comment: Your `Subclass` instance IS-A `Superclass`, so anywhere you can use a reference to a `Superclass` you can use a reference to a `Subclass`. It isn't clear what you want to do.

Comment: Well, the call to `super(...)` does not cause a new object to be created at all. All `super` does is construct the part the superclass requires you to construct. Your subclass *is* a superclass, but *extends* it: it may add methods or fields.

Comment: but I'm filling super(1, "first"); the superclass, its not a creation of it?

Comment: Yes, but there is not a separate superclass object. There is only one object, which is both an instance of the superclass and the subclass at the same time.

Comment: @SlavaVir just use `subclass.getName()` (make sure the `getName` is a `public` method)

Comment: are you trying to do this? `Superclass s = new Subclass();
        System.out.println(s.name);`

Comment: i have methode, which return subclass, can i somehow from this get Superclass object?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that will be answer:

```
Superclass superclass = (Superclass) subclass;
```

Comment: You don't need to cast at all.

Comment: if i asking superclass.getClass().getName() i have got subclass